# How to fill center view in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

In my android app, I have a relative layout whoes width fills the parent. How can I create 3 views so that the first view is a textview and is exactly 100dp in width, the third view is a edittext that is also 100dp wide, and the 2nd is a textview whoes width that fills up the center space.

```
[][   ][]
view 1, view 2, view 3
```

However, the first has to be left aligned, and the third has to be right aligned. The 2nd, needs to be in between, but fills up the space.

**Note: In java code.**

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want and the code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `layout_toLeftOf` and `layout_toRightOf` attributes to set the anchor points, and then set the `layout_width="wrap_content"` to stretch the view.

Here is a sample layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Text 1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="Text 2" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="Text 3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview1"
        android:text="TextView2" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hint="EditText3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try LinearLayout in this case. Set the 1st and 3rd with weight 0, 2nd with weight 1 and fill_parent.